# Update Statement mySQL issues

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, forms

I am having trouble updating the `posts` table of my database when a user updates a blog post they have made.

> Flow of events - user makes a blog post, its saved to DB then they can go back and edit it. Edit brings up a pre-filled html form populated with data from the `posts` table. Then the user can change the title and content and when they press update the posted values from the form should replace the title and content of the original post in `posts` DB all other columns remain unchanged.

Currently my database just doesn't seem to update, not sure why. Using a combination of html/php/sql/pdos to execute sql statements - getting very complex for my novice experience and any help is appreciated. 
Code (UPDATE statement is at bottom and most problematic):

```
// begin edit post
    if(isset($_GET['editPost'])) {
            $editPostId = $_GET['editPost'];
            $sqlEditPostCheck = <<<EOD
            SELECT author, id FROM posts WHERE author = '$currentUserId'
EOD;
            $stmtEditPostCheck = $pdo->prepare($sqlEditPostCheck);
            $stmtEditPostCheck->execute();

            $ableToEdit = false;

            while ($row = $stmtEditPostCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                if($editPostId === $row['id'] && $currentUserId === $row['author']) { $ableToEdit = true; }
            }

            if($ableToEdit === true) {
                $editPost_Title = "";
                $editPost_Content = "";

                $sqlEditPostPreFills = <<<EOD
            SELECT id, post_title, content FROM posts WHERE id="$editPostId"
EOD;
                $stmtEditPost = $pdo->prepare($sqlEditPostPreFills);
                $stmtEditPost->execute();   
                while ($row = $stmtEditPost->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $editPost_Title = $row['post_title'];
                    $editPost_Content = $row['content'];
                    $editPostId = $row['id'];
                }    

                $content = <<<EOD
                <form action="?profile&editPost="$editPostId" method="post">
            <h1>Edit Post</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input name="Epost_title" type="text" id="Epost_title" value="$editPost_Title" class="form-control">
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="Epost_content" id="Epost_content" value="" rows="6">$editPost_Content</textarea>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align: right;">
              <button type="submit" name="update" style="width: 30%;" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update</button>
            </div>
                </form>
            <hr />
EOD;

        } // end IF ableToEdit
        $updatedContent = "";
            if(isset($_POST['Epost_content'])) { $updatedContent = $_POST['Epost_content']; }

    $updatedTitle = "";
            if(isset($_POST['Epost_title'])) { $updatedTitle = $_POST['Epost_title']; }

    if(isset($_POST['Epost_content']) && isset($_POST['Epost_title'])) {
    $sqlUpdatePost = <<<EOD
    UPDATE posts SET post_title='$updatedTitle', content='$updatedContent' WHERE posts.id='$editPostId' AND posts.author='$currentUserId';
EOD;
            $stmtUpdate = $pdo->prepare($sqlUpdatePost);
            $stmtUpdate->execute();
                }
    }
    // end edit post
```

Answer (score -1):

This line look bad for me

```
<form action="?profile&editPost="$editPostId" method="post">
```

try to change it to

```
<form action="?profile&editPost=\"$editPostId\" method=\"post\">"
```

Comment: this still does not update the database. Quite honestly not sure what I want my form's action to be, also not sure if the form's action could be throwing off the update... thank you though!